# Bootstrap multiple checkbox required

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, required

im using bootstraps 3.0.1 and im trying to validate a multiple checkbox, I need to validate one at least. Is there no any way to do this bootstraps? Its hard to believe, but I couldn't find the way.

Here is my html,

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-4 text-right" for="interes">Categoría:</label>
                <div class="controls col-lg-8">
                    <label class="checkbox inline col-lg-6" for="interes-0">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="interes" id="interes-0" value="Gastronomía">
                        Gastronomía
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline col-lg-6" for="interes-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="interes" id="interes-1" value="Moda">
                        Moda
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline col-lg-6" for="interes-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="interes" id="interes-2" value="Cuidado Personal">
                        Cuidado Personal
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline col-lg-6" for="interes-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="interes" id="interes-3" value="Espectáculos">
                        Espectáculos
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Twitter Bootstrap doesn't do validation. You can easily [Google for a solution](https://www.google.se/search?q=javascript%20check%20if%20atleast%20one%20checkbox%20is%20selected).